# Wireless not work on Ubuntu 12.10 Realtek RTL8111/8168B

Tags: wireless

im from Argentina and i bought a notebook Bangho Futura 2521. I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 and i cant work the wifi...

The command lspci shows:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8723
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)
03:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI  
        Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
```

the command iwconfig shows:

eth0      no wireless extensions.
  lo        no wireless extensions.

Comment: The Realtek RTL8111/8168B are for **wired** network connections. Not for wireless.  Which wireless setup is used?

Answer (score 0):

Please run the terminal command:

```
lspci -nn
```

Is your device identified as 10ec:8723? If so, check post #24 here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2040656&page=3

There are a number of questions here that use an earlier version of the driver and error out at base.c:320:6: error: ‘IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER’. The later version I linked does not.